# Hello, I'm new to Android studio (Kotlin). Why is my TextView not displayed on the smartphone screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

My code xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/listitem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/listImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/one"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundImage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listName"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/listImage"
            android:text="@string/textbook1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:ignore="TextSizeCheck" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

My code kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class book1sem : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.book1sem)

        val myTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.listName)
        myTextView.setText(R.string.textbook1)

    }
}
```

My code strings.xml

```
<string name="textbook1">Глава 1: </string>
```

My code AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Zol"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".test2"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".test1"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".lab2"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".lab1"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".book2sem"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".book1sem"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

There are other TextView in my application, they are also not displayed. I have been trying for several days to find a way to solve this problem, I have already changed the code many times, and there was no result.
When creating the application, I used a ready-made template "Bottom Navigation Views Activity" and then added a "Button" to go to a new window (this is book1sem). Using the "Empty Views Activity" template, there were no problems with displaying text in the "TextView". I would like to continue working in the "Actions with lower Navigation Views" template, is it possible to use a template with the correct "TextView" display?
I will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, your class name is "book1sem" which is in place of "MainActivity"! Have you defined this class as your activity in Manifest file? I have run your code instead of your class name I used the default MainActivity and your code was fine!

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.listName)
        myTextView.setText(R.string.textbook1)
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! I will add information to my question. The fact is that in my application there is not only "MainActivity", so when I try to rename "MainActivity", I get the error "Redeclaration: MainActivity". When creating the application, I used a ready-made template "Bottom Navigation Views Activity" and then added a "Button" to go to a new window (this is book1sem). Using the "Empty Views Activity" template, there were no problems with displaying text in the "TextView".